# Bluetooth and another sketch

Tags: bluetooth

I uploaded a bluetooth sketch from IDE (File->Examples->Firmata->Standard Firmata) to Arduino Duo.

Now if I have a sensor attached to this Arduino, I can use bluetooth from another device (Raspberry pi or mobilephone) to read the sensor.

But what if I want to do something in the arduino itself? I see only one option
which is to edit the standardfirmata to read the sensor and do something. So multiple sketches running in one sketch.

Am I correct?

Answer (score -1):

If you programmed the Arduino to read the sensor and the do something else, what would you do if a second request to read the sensor came in before you had stopped doing something else?

I don't know anything about Firmata.  Could you add two sensor's, so the Pi could select to read from sensor 1 or sensor 2?  If you could do that then you alter the 'readSensor2()' function so it did 'Something else'.  This way you are exploiting any control/synchronisation logic within Firmata.  If you need 'readSensor1()' to automatically 'do something else' ever time it was called then couldn't you just tag it onto the end of 'readSensor1()'.